# Enabling the MathJax plugin?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

Several other stackexchange sites have enabled the use of the MathJax plugin to allow for typesetting of mathematical content using LaTeX code. On this site, however, this functionality does not appear to be present.

While this functionality is not necessary for much of the material posted here, it would facilitate more theoretical discussions of strategy and game theory/equilibria, such as in my recent answer on optimal bet sizing when one's range contains more than 50% value hands [here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/10597/4257).

How easy is it to enable this plugin on our site, and how would one go about doing it?

Comment: The general process: Make a Meta post that provides a strong argument for why MathJax should be abled on the site, and include a list of examples (in the question or posted as an answer) of questions on the site that would benefit from having MathJax enabled ([see this example on Space Exploration Meta](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/600)). Then, if the community agrees with the request, a mod can add the [status-review] tag to escalate it for staff attention, and we'll take a look and get back to you.

Comment: In this case, if it's very rarely useful/necessary to include MathJax, then we're less likely to enable it on the site. If there are a lot of questions where it'd be beneficial to be able to use MathJax, then we're more likely to consider implementing it for the site.